# Changing a particular value of an array, in Java, when it is a value of a HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, hashmap

I have a HashMap where the Key is an integer and the value is an array of double i.e.,

`HashMap<Integer, double[]> map = new HashMap<>();`

How do I change the value of a particular index in the double array?

One way of doing it is to get the double array for the required key, copy it to a temp array, modify the required index in the temp array and then, put the array into the map, for the same key i.e.,

double temp[] = map.get(i);

temp[10] = 3.142;

map.put(i,temp);

But, there must be a better implementation, right?

Comment: Use a List instead of a double array.

Comment: @CoryKendall - the problem as described doesn't require a list.  He is not inserting or removing an entry.  He is modifying an existing entry value.

Comment: @StephenC You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misconception here.  Your answer is already nearly the correct one, but it's better than you think it is.  `double[] temp = map.get(i)` does *not* make a copy: it returns a *reference* to the same array.  So

```
double[] temp = map.get(i);
temp[j] = 42.0;
```

does what you want it to do already.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick ... unless there is something about your problem description that I've misunderstood:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<Integer, double[]>();
...
doubles = map.get(i);
doubles[j] = 42.0;
```

Comment: I need to update the array which is in the HashMap. So, in your example, I need to do a map.put(i,doubles) right?

Comment: @FauxPas - No ... it is a reference that is passed by value.  All Java arguments and results are passed by value.